# Passing function parameter arguments from a script to another (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script (script1), that will call a second script (script2) on a remote computer. I have a function in script2 that send toast notification. My goal is to send the notification on a remote computer, so I have script1 that will invoke script2 on the remote computer.

I'm trying to find a way to define my function parameter arguments with script1, since script2 will run on the remote computer, I want it only to run the notification with the arguments given by script1.

Here's what I have so far :

Script1

```
Function Show-Notifications {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [string[]]
        $toastApp,
        [string[]]
        $toastTitle,
        [string[]]
        $toastText,
        [string[]]
        $toastImage
    )
    
    $ToastImageAndText02 = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]::ToastImageAndText02
    $TemplateContent = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]::GetTemplateContent($ToastImageAndText02)
    $TemplateContent.SelectSingleNode('//image[@id="1"]').SetAttribute('src', $toastImage)
    $TemplateContent.SelectSingleNode('//text[@id="1"]').InnerText = $toastTitle
    $TemplateContent.SelectSingleNode('//text[@id="2"]').InnerText = $toastText
    [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier($toastApp).Show($TemplateContent)
}

Show-Notifications -toastApp $args[0] -toastTitle $args[1] -toastText $args[2] -toastImage $args[3]
```

Script2

```
$hn = Read-Host -Prompt "Computer Hostname"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hn -FilePath C:\MyPath\script1.ps1 "Application" "Title" "Text"
Pause
```

When I run script1, I receive the following error :

```
Invoke-Command : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'Application'.
At C:\MyPath\script1.ps1:8 char:1
+ Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hn -FilePath C:\MyPath\script2.ps1 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], Parameter
   BindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell
   .Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Eventually, I would like to have each arguments define in a variable, so I can define what I want for each part of the notification, but for now I'm looking to make it work by defining the arguments in the script.

I've looked and tried different methods find on the web, but did not work either.

I tried using `$args = @()` and `$args += ("-toastApp", $arg1)`, but I received an error where the content of `$arg1` wasn't showing so I backtracked seeing it was getting worse the way I was doing it.

Tried defining more details to my parameters as well, like position arguments or ValueFromPipeline, but I did not achieve my goal this way either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with how you are using `Invoke-Command`. It does not know what to do with the list of arguments that you want to provide to the script that you specified. Specify that those are arguments for the script by using the `-ArgumentList` parameter.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hn -FilePath C:\MyPath\script1.ps1 -ArgumentList @("Application","Title","Text")
```

While you're at it, if all that script does is create a function, and then call that same function, you can skip making the function and just have the script itself accept the parameters and perform the actions. Just remove lines 1, 20, and 22 so the script looks like this:

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param (
    [string[]]
    $toastApp,
    [string[]]
    $toastTitle,
    [string[]]
    $toastText,
    [string[]]
    $toastImage
)

$ToastImageAndText02 = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]::ToastImageAndText02
$TemplateContent = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]::GetTemplateContent($ToastImageAndText02)
$TemplateContent.SelectSingleNode('//image[@id="1"]').SetAttribute('src', $toastImage)
$TemplateContent.SelectSingleNode('//text[@id="1"]').InnerText = $toastTitle
$TemplateContent.SelectSingleNode('//text[@id="2"]').InnerText = $toastText
[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier($toastApp).Show($TemplateContent)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Just tried the code, unfortunately it gave me an error, but it's progress :

`Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At D:\Code\PSscript\PSnotif\PSnotifCaller.ps1:4 char:1
+ Invoke-Command -FilePath D:\Code\PSscript\PSnotif\PSnotif.ps1 -Arg ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand`

Comment: I'm thinking about parameters attribute maybe? Also I'm not on my usual working station  as when I did the post so maybe it's just me as well

Comment: Your comment truncates the error, but the code we both referenced has `Invoke-Command` with  `-ComputerName $hn` as the first argument, but the error lacks that. Is that parameter somewhere later, or did you miss that?

Comment: Yeah I had to edit the code because of the environment, I didn't had access to a remote computer. I do now, and tried to rerun the code with a remote computer in my usual environment, and it worked out perfectly! Thank you for the help!